# Lodash : Regex pattern stored in a variable

Tags: lodash

```
var s="Fred";
_.replace('Hi Fred', s, 'Barney');

Result : "Hi Barney"
```

I want to know how to use replace function when regex pattern is stored in a variable.

```
var s="Fred";
_.replace('Hi Fred', /s/, 'Barney');

Result : "Hi Fred"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't specific to lodash, really. You just need to create the regex with the `RegExp` constructor instead of the literal syntax:

```
var s="Fred";
var r=new RegExp(s);
var result = _.replace('Hi Fred', r, 'Barney');

console.log(result);
// "Hi Barney"
```

Check here for more help:

[How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)